# Can´t get accentuation to work on messages sent with my email form. Anyone can give me a hand? Here is my code:

Tags: php, forms, email, diacritics

**This is what the message is showing:**
CÃ£o aÃ§orda Ã¡gua cÃ´co teste acentuaÃ§Ã£o

**This is what I wanted it to show:**
Cão açorda água côco teste acentuação

Can someone give me a hand? I would be very grateful.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!empty($_POST['contactname']) && !empty($_POST['contactemail']) && !empty($_POST['contactmessage'])) {
        $to = 'email@gmail.com'; // Your e-mail address here.
        $body = "\nNCliente: {$_POST['contactname']}\nEmail: {$_POST['contactemail']}\n\n\n{$_POST['contactmessage']}\n\n";
        mail($to, "Mensagem de ", $body, "From: {$_POST['contactemail']}"); // E-Mail subject here.
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an encoding problem. If you want to display characters like 'ç', typical from portuguese language, you need to decode your text parameters to the UTF-8 pattern. That way, they are going to be displayed properly.

To do that, you could try using **utf8_decode(string)** function from PHP. Something like this:

```
$contactname = utf8_decode($_POST['contactname']);
```

**EDIT:** Your code would look like this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if(!empty($_POST['contactname']) && !empty($_POST['contactemail']) && !empty($_POST['contactmessage'])) {

    //this is the part where you convert to utf8 pattern
    $namecontact = utf8_decode($_POST['contactname']);
    $messagecontact = utf8_decode($_POST['contactmessage']);

    $to = 'email@gmail.com'; // Your e-mail address here.

    $body = "\nNCliente: " .$namecontact. "\nEmail: {$_POST['contactemail']}\n\n\n". $messagecontact ."\n\n";
    mail($to, "Mensagem de ", $body, "From:" . $namecontact); // E-Mail subject here.
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, Thank you so much for you prompt answer. So how should my code look like? Where should I add the string? I'm new at this and trying to set up my website :( Can you help?

Comment: In this case, as i believe you want to add the contactemail information to that last part where you call the mail function, i believe that instead of using: mail($to, "Mensagem de JRJ Ricoh", $body, "From: {$_POST['contactemail']}");

You could use this, after doing that conversion in $contactname variable as i suggested: mail($to, "Mensagem de JRJ Ricoh", $body, "From: $contactname");

Comment: Like this:    <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!empty($_POST['contactname']) && !empty($_POST['contactemail']) && !empty($_POST['contactmessage'])) {
 $to = 'email@gmail.com'; // Your e-mail address here.
 $body = "\nNCliente: {$_POST['contactname']}\nEmail: {$_POST['contactemail']}\n\n\n{$_POST['contactmessage']}\n\n";
 mail($to, "Mensagem", $body, "From: $contactname"); // E-Mail subject here.
    }
 

}
?>

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer so that it has the whole code

Comment: Just a little info: what php version are you using?

Comment: I figured it out. I should use decode instead of encode. Check the new edit:

Comment: Hi Pedro I'm using PHP Version 5.6.30

Comment: You are awesome!!!!! Thank so much for your help. Accents are now showing :) Is there a way to see the name of the person who is sending the email? when i receive an email from the form,  I'm getting (remetente desconhecido) instead of the name of the person who is sending. Is this possible?

Comment: No problems! I think if you can add it in the additional parameters, but i'm not really sure. Try this: mail($to, "Mensagem de ", $body, "From:" . $namecontact, 'From: webmaster@example.com'); in the mail section. Also, if you think my answer was useful, please don't forget to accept it as right.

Comment: Hi Pedro :)  I've noticed if we only use one word on contact name it will show on the email. However if we insert two words (name and surname for example) it will show as "remetente desconhecido". Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: I think maybe it's because it has a blank space between both names and it doesn't identify it as a string. Yet, i don't know how to solve like this. Adding the "From" field as i suggested didn't work?

Comment: Hi Pedro :( No I didn't fix it. However, you have helped me a lot already.  The accentuation was a massive problem. I've posted another question to solve this. Maybe someone as nice as you can help me fix it. Fingers crossed. And once again, THANK YOU LOTS!